# DataGridView Filtering Using BindingSource (Of CustomClassObjects)

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource, bindinglist

I want to filter through my DataGridView data. My DataGridView's DataSource is bound to a `BindingSource`. The BindingSource contains a list of objects from my `clsBillHeader` class.

Here is the first bit of code:

```
Dim bSource As New BindingSource
bSource.DataSource = clsBillHeader.GetAll()
dgvBills.DataSource = bSource
bSource.Filter = "JobNumber Like '100%'" //Filter doesn't actually work
```

**GetAll()**

```
Public Shared Function GetAll() As List(Of clsBillHeader)
    Dim mycn As New SqlConnection(connection)
    Dim mycmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Headers", mycn)
    mycn.Open()
    Dim myreader As SqlDataReader = mycmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim myList As New List(Of clsBillHeader)
    While myreader.Read
        Dim item As New clsBillHeader()
        SetByReader(myreader, item) //Sets all values correctly (such as forein keys)
        myList.Add(item)
    End While
    mycn.Close()
    Return myList
End Function
```

This successfully returns all my values needed as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: BindingSource]

---

The problem is it doesn't filter through anything ... my `JobNumber Like '100%'` doesn't seem to be filtering at all. As seen below:

[image: Unwanted Results]

I should just be getting the first two numbers but it returns everything else ...

**Why am I not using DataView to use filtering?**

Well, DataView would cause me to use a DataTable that is directly bound to the SQL table. Some values in my table are foreign keys and would need to be transformed into something more meaningful than integers.

Ex: `FK_Author = 1` would be the value in the DataTable. Instead, I use my SetByReader to transform it into `Author = "Alex"`. That's why I want to use a BindingSource.

All I need is to filter through a DataGridView bound to a class of `clsBillHeaders`. Has anyone had the same problem?

### EDIT

Take a look at this screenshot. Apparently it doesn't support Filtering ...

[image: NoFilter Support]

Why does my BindingSource variable have this by default?

Comment: What is that `BindingListView`?

Comment: I think `BindingListView` is generic class so you've to use `BindingList(Of T)`

Comment: BindingList class doesn't implement the IBindingListView interface. There are not many classes that do but `BindingSource` and `DataView` do. I thought BindingList did but unfortunately it doesn't ...

Comment: Am sorry BindingListView(Of T) ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I editted my question, it's clearer now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I understand the problem now. Actually your datasource doesn't support Filtering.
[BindingSource.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx) will work only when your datasource implements `IBindingListView`

> Only underlying lists that implement the IBindingListView interface support filtering.

So, to make it work you've to change your underlying datasource. If you don't wanna use `DataView` for some reason try using `BindingSource` itself as a datasource.

Edit:
May this links help how to support filtering http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winformsue/archive/2008/05/19/implementing-filtering-on-the-ibindinglistview.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winformsue/archive/2007/12/07/implementing-the-ibindinglistview-for-filtering.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Check my  first  code bit above, is this what you mean? The DataSource of my BindingSource is equal to the list of `clsBillHeaders`. Then my DataGridView's datasource is equal to the BindingSource.

Comment: Try adding elements to `BindingSource` itself, not to use `List` and set it as a datasource to `BindingSource`. if you do so then your underlying datasource is `List`? you see the difference?

Comment: I see. I just tried: `Dim bSource As New BindingSource` and then used `bSource.Add(item)` where `item` is an object of type clsBillHeader ... Therefore the DataSource of `bSource` was empty but there was a count of 4069 in the `List` attribute of `bSource` ... Yet it doesn't filter :(

Comment: Something interesting Sriram ... I checked the attributes of `bSource` and it states: `SupportsFiltering: False` ... How do I get my `BindingSource` object to support filtering? I thought it did by default...!

Comment: Ino rder for my BindingSource to support filtering it must be part of IBindingListView ... Not sure how to do this but in any case, +1 for the help.

Comment: Even I don't know why `BindingSource` doesnt support filtering. researching on it. wil let you know once found

Comment: I ended up building a dataset with my list of object values. The dataset was then used along with a DataView which had the IBindingListView implementation. I'll accept  your answer because you helped me get on the right path and figure stuff out. I learned a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I found a quick and simple solution, I just convert the List to a DataTable, here is the link
[How to fill a datatable with List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076034/how-to-fill-a-datatable-with-listt)

Comment: [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) has a method to do this : `.ToDataTable()`
This is working well.