# How do I filter my datagirdview using a textbox?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using project2;
   namespace project
    {
        public enum TankData
        {
            Name = 0,
            Cannon =1,
            Weight =2,
            TopSpeed =3,
            Armor =4,
            YearProduced =5,
            Production =6,
            CruisingSpeed =7,
            TurretTurn =8,
            Classifaction= 9,
            Crew =10,
            NATOorNonNATO =11,
            Period =12,
            Era = 13,
        }
            
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
    
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
            #region Event Handlers
    
        

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadData();                
        }
    
            #endregion
    
            #region Class Helpers
              
            protected void LoadData()
            {
                List<TankClass> tanks = new List<TankClass>();
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\bluehalo\Documents\tank chart 2.txt");
                
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    TankClass tank = new TankClass(lines[i].ToString());
    
                    tanks.Add(tank);    
                }
    
                dataGridView1.DataSource = tanks;
            }
     
            #endregion
    
            private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               
            }
        }
    }
```

So I've been trying to filter my datagridview using a text box and I have tried using:
"(DataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '{0}%' OR Name LIKE '% {0}%'", TextBox.Text);"

but it kept returning a null error. Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: here's the TankClass class, sorry I forgot to put this in earlier.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using project;

namespace project2
{
    class TankClass
    {
        protected bool _isLoaded = false;

        #region Class Property
        public string Tankname { get; set; }
        public int Caliber { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public double TopSpeed { get; set; }
        public int Armor { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Production { get; set; }
        public int CruisingSpeed { get; set; }
        public int TurretTurn { get; set; }
        public string Classification { get; set; }
        public string Era { get; set; }
        public int Crew { get; set; }
 
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Faction { get; set; }
       

        #endregion

        #region Constructor(s)

        public TankClass()
        {   
        }

        public TankClass(string concatProps)
        {
            string[] values = concatProps.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Tankname = values[(int)TankData.Name];
            Caliber = Convert.ToInt32(values[(int)TankData.Cannon]);
            Weight = Convert.ToDouble(values[(int)TankData.Weight]);
            TopSpeed = Convert.ToDouble(values[(int)TankData.TopSpeed]);
            Armor = Convert.ToInt32(values[(int)TankData.Armor]);
            Year = Convert.ToInt32(values[(int)TankData.YearProduced]);
            Production = Convert.ToInt32(values[(int)TankData.Production]);
            CruisingSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(values[(int)TankData.CruisingSpeed]);
            TurretTurn = Convert.ToInt32(values[(int)TankData.TurretTurn]);
            Classification = values [(int)TankData.Classifaction];
            Crew = Convert.ToInt32(values[(int)TankData.Crew]);
            Era = values[(int)TankData.Era];
            Country = values[(int)TankData.NATOorNonNATO];
            Faction = values[(int)TankData.Period];
            _isLoaded = true;
        }
        public TankClass(string tankname, int caliber, float weight, float topSpeed, int armor, int year, int numbers, int cruisingSpeed, int turretTurn, string classification, int crew, string country, string nATOorNotNATO, string timePeriod)
        {
            Tankname = tankname;
            Caliber = caliber;
            Weight = weight;
            TopSpeed = topSpeed;
            Armor = armor;
            Year = year;
            Production = numbers;
            CruisingSpeed = cruisingSpeed;
            TurretTurn = turretTurn;
            Classification = classification;
            Crew = crew;
            Era = country;
            Country = nATOorNotNATO;
            Faction = timePeriod;
            _isLoaded = true;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason you're getting the Null Reference Exception is because of `(DataGridView.DataSource as DataTable)` - your datasource isn't a DataTable, it's a `List<TankClass>`. But, it's not as simple as filtering the tanks using the same syntax as _"Only underlying lists that implement the `IBindingListView` interface support filtering. 
`BindingList<T>` does not appear to implement IBindingListView - and since it is the underlying list, your collection will not filter."_ [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10074142/43846)

Comment: There's a link in the comments on the above answer to a class you can use as a wrapper to enable filtering (and sorting) with a `List<T>` in a DataGridView, but it's been archived -  I posted one though some years ago in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19114079/43846) which I used in a similar situation. There's a comment at the top showing how it's used.

Comment: (Once you have this information - DataGridView, Sort, IBindlingList - you can find  [many](https://web.archive.org/web/20130618073117/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winformsue/archive/2008/05/19/implementing-filtering-on-the-ibindinglistview.aspx) [other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms993236(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) [implementations](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31418/Implementing-a-Sortable-BindingList-Very-Very-Quic))

Comment: But if I can trust my long term memory, I _believe_ that the one I used was written originally by Stack Overflow's own Marc Gravell - it was easy to use, and worked very well, so I'd recommend that.

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to programming so I'm a little bit confused on what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to filter *and* sort, then you can use the `SortableList<T>` as above.

If you really just want to filter, though, it's as simple as this: store the tanks list, and assign the datasource as a subset of `tanks` when the filter changes:

```
// 'tanks' is stored as a field when loaded from disk
private List<TankClass> tanks;

protected void LoadData()
{
    tanks = new List<TankClass>();
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\bluehalo\Documents\tank chart 2.txt");
            
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        TankClass tank = new TankClass(lines[i].ToString());
        tanks.Add(tank);    
    }
    
    dataGridView1.DataSource = tanks;
}
```

And when you want to filter:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // name contains text
    dataGridView1.DataSource = tanks.Where(t => t.Name.IndexOf(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1).ToList()
}
```

Comment: Sorry to be disturbing you again, but I added "private List<TankClass> tanks;" and "dataGridView1.DataSource = tanks.Where(t => t.Tankname.Contains(textBox1.Text, 
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();" but I get two errors, one for the list saying "Field 'Form1.tanks' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null project" and the "t.Tankname.Contains" having the error of "No overload for method 'Contains' takes 2 arguments"

Comment: _Field 'Form1.tanks' is never assigned to_ - but it is assigned in LoadData as above? and _No overload for method 'Contains' takes 2 arguments_ it should go to [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Contains_System_String_System_StringComparison_) - maybe you should update the code in your question? I had to guess quite a lot.

Comment: Sorry I did to forget to mention a few parts of the TanksClass class, I'll edit the code for you to see it

Comment: Updated the answer, which I didn't test properly first - sorry about that!

Comment: I'm still getting the warning "Field 'Form1.tanks' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null" and every time I type something into the text box to filter I return a null error, "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source"

Comment: Have you changed your LoadData method to have this? `tanks = new List<TankClass>();`? This will assign the field.

Comment: My bad didn't change that, I've fixed the issue but how would I filter for an int or float?

Comment: also now I'm getting the issue where when I try to do more than one filter, only one result will filter.

Comment: To filter on a number, use `t => t.TopSpeed > 100` - and for multiple filters, use `||` ('or').

Comment: Hi, sorry to disturb you once more but I'm getting a method error when trying to filter an int and float with this line of code "dataGridView1.DataSource =
                tanks.Where(t => t.Year > 100(yearsearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1).ToList();" and how would I do this using a combobox @stuartd ?

Comment: I'm not sure what `dataGridView1.DataSource = tanks.Where(t => t.Year > 100(yearsearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1).ToList();` is trying to do here?

Comment: I figured it out, but thanks a lot for helping me and being so patient with be, sorry if I caused any inconvenience, but thanks once again.

Comment: Good to hear. Happy to have helped!