# manually populating a dataset or datatable in C# from a string or array

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I want to write business logic with data in a dataset.

The data will be of the below format

**`AssociateId`**             **`Action`**                                   **`Time`**

```
1          Login     12/12/2012 20:33
2          Login     12/13/2012 20:33
1          Login     12/14/2012 20:33
2          Game page 12/15/2012 20:33
1          Home page 12/16/2012 20:33
1          Map       12/17/2012 20:33
```

I want to convert this to a dataset, i dont want to make database call and populate it from there.

I am assigning it to a string and converting it to an array by splitting using the space. How can convert that array or this string as a whole to a dataset or datatable??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a `DataTable` in memory and add it to any `DataSet`.  Something like:

```
var myTable = new DataTable();
myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AssociateId"));
myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Action"));
myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Time"));

var row = myTable.NewRow();
row["AssociateId"] = 1;
row["Action"] = "Login";
row["Time"] = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12, 20, 33, 0);

myTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

But does it really *need* to be a `DataTable`?  Creating a custom object seems like a cleaner and more robust way of holding the data in memory.  Something as simple as:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int AssociateID { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create a list of them:

```
var myList = new List<MyClass>();
myList.Add(new MyClass
{
    AssociateID = 1,
    Action = "Login",
    Time = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12, 20, 33, 0)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to fill the list from your required data.
and then fill dataset from that list.

pls follow link, hope this will help you.

[How to fill a datatable with List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076034/how-to-fill-a-datatable-with-listt)