# How to convert collections to DataTable for Ado.Net SqlDataAdapter.Update?

Tags: c#, ado.net

How to finish the following function which accept three collection parameters for deleted, inserted and updated records and convert the collections to a `DataTable` for `DataAdapter` to update the table?

I found a way to convert List to DataTable at [How to fill a datatable with List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076034/how-to-fill-a-datatable-with-listt?rq=1). However, it doesn't set the insert, update and delete flags in DataTable?

```
void Save(
    IEnumerable<int> deleted, 
    IEnumerable<Poco1> inserted, 
    IEnumerable<Poco1> updated)
{
    var dt = new DataTable(); 
    .... // Initialize dt with deleted, inserted and update?

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStr))
    {
        con.Open();
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table", con);
        da.Update(dt);
    }
}
```

Or is there a better way to update the database table from these three collections? (C# 3.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your going to want to also define the Insert, Update and Delete commands:

```
// Create the other commands.
da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("...how to insert");

da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("...how to update");

da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("...how to delete");
```

Alternatively you can try to use DbCommandBuilder to do it for you at runtime:

```
// Create the DbCommandBuilder.
DbCommandBuilder builder = factory.CreateCommandBuilder();
builder.DataAdapter = da;

// Get the insert, update and delete commands.
da.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
da.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
da.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
```

Next you need to define the DataTables to match the table you are targeting:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(add your columns...)
```

Then you need to add rows to the DataTable, making sure to mark the row as inserted, updated or deleted.

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["your column"] = ...
// Don't forget to add the row to the table!
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
// Once the row is added then go ahead and mark it as deleted, modified or new
dr.Delete()
// or
dr.SetAdded();
// or
dr.SetModified();
```

Comment: I got the exception of "Additional information: SetAdded and SetModified can only be called on DataRows with Unchanged DataRowState." when calling `dr.SetModified();`, etc.

Comment: Try calling .AcceptChanges() on the rows before setting their state.

Answer (score 0):

It wont work the way you are doing , do like this

```
 using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStr))
    {
        con.Open();
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table", con);
        var ds=new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        var dt= ds.Tables[0];
        // all deleted rows 
        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows.ToList())
{
    if(deleted.ToList().Contains((int)dr["id"]))
{
        dr.Delete();
}
//all updated rows 
foreach(var poco in updated.ToList()
{
  DataRow dr = table.Select("id="+poco.id).FirstOrDefault();
  dr["field1]=poco.feild1 
  ....set all updated values 

}
//all inserted rows 
foreach(var poco in inserted.ToList())
{
  var dr= dt.NewRow();
  dr["id"]=poco.id;
  ..set all fields
  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
}
        dt.Accept
        da.Update(dt);
    }
```