# C# Datatable sorting column without same values after each other

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, datatable

I have a datatable output like shown below, I'm trying to sort / order the rows in a way so that the values of the 
column containing test, test1, test2 will not be repeated after each other.

Basicly I just want to "mix" the rows, so the same value of the column is not repeated (as far as possiple)

The image shows 4 columns out of the 21 in the datatable [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMTPl.png)

Comment: Why `test2` first and not `test1`? One time descending and later ascending.

Comment: @Rango It appears that the order is based on the group count (i.e. there are 6 `test2`, 4 `test`, and 2 `test1`)

Comment: Because it does not matter witch value comes first, what matters is that as far as possiple, the values should mixed, so that the same value don't appear after each other

Comment: @Rufus L Indeed they are - I've added a image for better understanding

Comment: `I just want to "mix" the rows` you could add an invisible column and assign a rank/score for each row following your rules and sort by that.  The value could even be a shuffle of a sequence but that would not restrict repeats

Comment: Can you give an example to produce the wanted output?

Comment: Is there any reason your desired output is missing a `test` element?

Comment: @Rufus L What do you mean?

Comment: I mean in your question you show the desired output, there is a `test` element missing, and an extra `test1` compared to the sample input.

Comment: The datatable is dynamic, and can contains 5 test 100 test1 345345 test2 etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample using LINQ to process it. This uses the ever forgotten two parameter lambda version of `Select` to get a position value for each `type`. Since no column names were shown, I called the first column `type` and the `other` column stands for the rest of the data.

```
var db = new[] {
    new { type = "test", other = 1 },
    new { type = "test", other = 2 },
    new { type = "test", other = 3 },
    new { type = "test", other = 4 },
    new { type = "test1", other = 5 },
    new { type = "test1", other = 6 },
    new { type = "test2", other = 7 },
    new { type = "test2", other = 8 },
    new { type = "test2", other = 9 },
    new { type = "test2", other = 10 },
};

var ans = db.GroupBy(d => d.type)
            .Select(dg => dg.Select((d, i) => new { d, i }))
            .SelectMany(dig => dig)
            .GroupBy(di => di.i)
            .SelectMany(dig => dig.Select(di => di.d));
```

Basically this is an idiom (now I want a cool name like [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)) for pivoting an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable>>` which I then flatten.

I created an extension method to capture the pivot central idiom.

```
public static class IEnumerableIEnumerableExt {
    // Pivot IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> by grouping matching positions of each sub-IEnumerable<T>
    // src - source data
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Pivot<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> src) =>
        src.Select(sg => sg.Select((s, i) => new { s, i }))
            .SelectMany(sg => sg)
            .GroupBy(si => si.i)
            .Select(sig => sig.Select(si => si.s));

    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<DataRow> src) {
        var ans = src.First().Table.Clone();
        foreach (var r in src)
            ans.ImportRow(r);
        return ans;
    }
}
```

With this extension method, the answer becomes:

```
var ans2 = db.GroupBy(d => d.type)
             .Pivot()
             .SelectMany(dg => dg);
```

And if the source is a `DataTable`, you can do this:

```
var ansdt = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("type"))
              .Pivot()
              .SelectMany(rg => rg)
              .ToDataTable();
```

Since there isn't really an easy way to order or sort a `DataTable`, I added an extension method to convert the `IEnumerable<DataRow>` to a new `DataTable`.

Comment: How does this sort / order the rows in the datatable to the needed output? I tried to fiddle with it in VS but it doesn't fit my needs I think. The datatable columns and rows are filled from a mysql dataadapter

Comment: @NicklasChristensen The Pivot converts a stream of streams to a new stream of streams, with the result sub-streams containing the nth element of each source stream. Did you try to run the sample code? This will easily work with a `DataTable`, just change the reference to `type` to a `.Field<string>("fieldname")`. I added an example.

Comment: @NicklasChristensen I realized you might want the answer as a `DataTable`, but sorting / processing `DataTable`s isn't really possible, so I added an extension method to convert the answer into a new `DataTable`. Really, working with `DataTable`s is somewhat obsolete when using a SQL Server.

Comment: I would rep you if I could. Your solution was the closest I came, then I figured out that what I was actually looking for was not this. The answer is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @NicklasChristensen Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Rango's answer is more concise, but since I worked on one, here it is. You can use `GroupBy` to group the items, and then add items to a new list from each group, in a loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = new List<string>
    {
        "test", "test", "test", "test", "test1", "test1",
        "test2", "test2", "test2", "test2", "test2", "test2",
    };

    var groups = data.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count());
    var maxGroupCount = groups.Max(g => g.Count());
    var orderedData = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxGroupCount; i++)
    {
        orderedData.AddRange(groups.Where(group => group.Count() > i)
            .Select(group => group.ElementAt(i)));
    }

    orderedData.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: That is the output that I want, but how can I apply this to a datatable, and maybe I forgot to mention that the datatable is dynmically filled from a mysql adapter, having 21 columns, but this is the output that I am looking for. Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076034/how-to-fill-a-datatable-with-listt

Comment: As I forgot to mention, the datatable has 21 columns and your sample as based on a single column (Again sorry for not being clear)